# sql query with if condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a form in that form there are dropdown box i populate from table called "service" here the code that populate the drop-down box

```
<?php 
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM service"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){ 
$select= '<select name="service">';   
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
  $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['name'].</option>'; 
} 
}       
$select.='</select>'; 
echo $select;  
?>
```

for example the drop-down will be something like that

```
    <select name="service">
<option value="1">service1</option>
<option value="2">service2</option>
<option value="3">service3</option>
</select>
```

the form insert data to table called clients

what i want to do is for example if i select the first item in the drop-down box "service1" and submit the form and the data get saved in table "clients" if i try to add another  service i don't want item "service1" to appear again so it can only be chosen once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you gave table names and structures so I wasn't guessing at your answer so much.  This is pseudo coded since I have no idea what any of your table relations are

```
SELECT id,name 
FROM service 
where id not in (select service_id from clients 
                where client = whichever_is_currently_logged_in_by_id?)
```

Comment: can you show me small example of the correct table structure of how the two table should be like do i need to have same column in the two tables ???

Comment: Easiest way from what I see here is a service table, a client table, then a third table that links the two.  So service is id,name.  Lets say you have a client table that has id,client_name, other_data.  You would then want a third table that contains id,client_id, service_id, informtation_from_your_form_submitted (that could be 1 column or 50 columns, pending what informtion you are inserting).  The 3rd table to link the two keeps redundant data to a minimum (if you held the service_ID in the client table, you'd have 1 row per service_ID and ultimately repeat client info for each sevice_id).

Comment: select count(1) from client_sevice where service_id = 1.  That will give you a quick count of the number of times service1 appears (well, service_id 1).  Select client,count(1) from client_service where service_id = 1 group by client having count(1) >= 25.  That will check to see if any single client has 25 entries matching service_id 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to a SQL query by adding a "WHERE" clause.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_MyTable WHERE 'name' = "Jim"
```

Comment: Jake, I think you want to switch the quotes for SQL Server.